# 'itemListElement' not recognized in 'HowTo' schema

Tags: schema.org, rdfa

Based on the Microdata example in http://schema.org/HowTo and extrapolating syntax from the Microdata vs RDFa example in http://schema.org/hasOfferCatalog (there seem to be so few actual examples of RDFa to find?), I put together something like so:

```html
<main vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="HowTo">
  <h1><span property="name">How to do the Hokey Pokey</span></h1>
  <ol property="steps">
    <li property="itemListElement" typeof="HowToStep">
      <img alt="step 1" src="step1.jpg" align="left">
      <p property="itemListElement" typeof="HowToDirection">
        put your left hand in</p></li>
    <li property="itemListElement" typeof="HowToStep">
      <img alt="step 2" src="step2.jpg" align="left">
      <p property="itemListElement" typeof="HowToDirection">
        put your left hand out</p></li>
```

But, when put into [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/), I get:

> The property `itemListElement` is not recognized by Google for an object of type `HowTo`.

[Yandex's validator](https://webmaster.yandex.com/tools/microtest/) also says:

> WARNING: http://schema.org/itemListElement field not specified in http://schema.org/HowTo

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to specify the `HowToSection` (or `HowToStep`) type as value for the [`steps`](http://schema.org/steps) property.

The Microdata example uses:

```html
<div id="steps" itemprop="steps" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/HowToSection">
```

The equivalent RDFa would be:

```html
<div id="steps" property="steps" typeof="HowToSection">
```

If you aren’t providing an `ItemList`/`CreativeWork` value for the `steps` property, you are providing a `Text` value (this is what you are doing in your example markup). But you can’t add properties (like `itemListElement`) to a `Text` value.